# Atlas layouts in QGIS with two different layers with shared ID

Tags: qgis, atlas

I have a set of municipalities, and I am exporting the results for all of them after analyzing a set of variables using Earth Observation data.

Each page in my layout has two maps:

1. The full municipality extension
2. A zoomed-in view of the town itself

As far as I know, Atlas only accepts one layer as a coverage layer. This issue could have been solved if the town was located at the centroid of the polygon, as the map's zoom level could be adjusted. However, barely any of the towns are positioned exactly in the middle of the municipality. Therefore, I need to iterate through all the pages, defining the map extent in Item Properties.

To prevent this from happening, I have created a point layer (town_centroids) that shares an ID with the municipality layer (municipalities). Using this point layer, I want to define the extent of the 2nd map based on the X and Y (min and max) of the current Atlas view, matching both IDs by the Page name of the Coverage Layer.

Am I on the right track? If I am, what expression should I input for the XY map extents in Item Properties? Or does anyone have a better approach to solve this issue?